# Using concatenated verbatim strings as keys in C# NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, string

I have been trying to use verbatim strings to create a string that I will be using as a key to reference value in a NameValueCollection.

The string I want is this `\\storage\local`
So I create a verbatim string

```
string key = @"\\storage\local";
```

Later I use it as a key in on a NameValue collection Like this

```
string value = Settings[key];
```

When I debug the above code and look at the key, it shows `\\\\storage\\local` with the escape sequence format. Since this is not the key that is in my settings, I am not getting a value.
Please help me understand how I can use the `\\storage\local` as the key on my collection.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue, the printable representation in the debugger is not the same as the actual string - it has to render the escape sequences. This is normal and expected behavior.

Comment: It is the debugger which shows your values as `\\\\storage\\local` but in real they are `\\storage\local`, so the issue is somewhere else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The \\\\ is just a debugger representation (with escaped backslashes). This is the expected behaviour. You can test it works by using the following sample:

```
string value = "Some value";
Settings[@"\\storage\local"] = value;
string value1 = Settings[@"\\storage\local"];
string value2 = Settings["\\\\storage\\local"];
```

Both value1 and value2 will have the same result which is "Some value"